# JNA Using macros

Tags: java, jna

Is it possible to map The following Macro function with JNA?

```
int ListView_FindItem(
 HWND hwnd,
int iStart,
const LPLVFINDINFO plvfi
);
```

I've tried to map this function with StdCallLibraryb, but that does not seem to work
(Function not found exception is thrown).

Basically i am trying find the index of a particular item in List view of desktop.
I have the name of the item i intend to find.

EDIT: 
i have tried using the send message feature, i get the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function   
'GetMessage': The specified procedure could not be found.

at com.sun.jna.Function.<init>(Function.java:179)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:347)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:327)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:203)
at $Proxy0.GetMessage(Unknown Source)
at javaapplication4.Main.main(Main.java:43)
Java Result: 1
```

This is the code i used

```
public class Main {


  public static class LVFINDINFO extends Structure {
     public int    flags =1002;
     public String psz = "new folder3";
     public LPARAM  lParam ;
     public POINT   pt;
     public int    vkDirection;
}
  public static class MSG extends Structure {
    public HWND hWnd;
    public int message;
    public int  wParam =-1;
    public LVFINDINFO lParam1;
    public int time;
    public POINT pt;

    public MSG(LVFINDINFO lParam) {
        lParam1 = lParam;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    User32 user32 = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("User32", User32.class);

    LVFINDINFO i = new LVFINDINFO();
    MSG m = new MSG(i);
    user32.GetMessage(m, user32.GetDesktopWindow(), 0, 0);

    System.out.println(user32.GetMessage(m, user32.GetDesktopWindow(), 0, 0));
}

}
```

Comment: I think you want SendMessage() or PostMessage(), not GetMessage().

Comment: And once you've called the correct function, call GetLastError() to see if it executed correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Since a macro exists purely at compile-time, there's no way to call it using JNA.

You'll need to see what the macro actually does and do that instead. According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761242%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) it sends [the `LVM_FINDITEM` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774903%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). You need to find out how to send that message using JNA.

Comment: Hi Joachim thanks for the quick reply. i have edited my answer contains the problem i face when i used message feature